# Highlight pads of connected nets when dragging

Tags: altium

I recall that Altium has some option that would highlight pads with matching nets on other components when dragging something in the pcb editor. I wasn't able to find the option. Was it removed in AD20 perhaps?

Comment: That does sound convenient. Allegro doesn't have that so I move the components in a circular motion and exercise my visual cortex's line and motion tracking capabilities.

Comment: I haven't seen that before, but you can control-click a net and it will be highlighted.

Comment: shift for me, but yes, thanks!